# The list of tag badges is all sorts of messed up

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, tag-badges

I was just browsing through the [list of bronze tag badges here on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze) and noticed that some of them get cut off by an ellipsis. I was curious which tags they actually were, but that information is not present at all on the page.

Take, for example, these three badges for Stack Exchange related tags:

> [image: List of tag badges]
>   <sub>It's a Stack Exchange muffin!</sub>

The first one is obviously for the [stackexchange](/questions/tagged/stackexchange) tag because it is not ellipsed.

However, the next two get ellipsed to just "stackexchange" without any further information.

- The tag at the right should not *also* be ellipsed. I understand why it is done at the left - the column is only so wide. But the description has *plenty* of space to display the full tag name.
- Hovering over the badge itself just displays **"bronze badge:"** in the tooltip without any further description after it. Not very helpful.
- Hovering over the badge itself also reveals that the link only has the "stackexchange" part in the slug at the end of the URL.
- Hovering over the tag at the left opens up the tag popup for the [stackexchange](/questions/tagged/stackexchange) tag rather than the actual tag it's describing, probably because it's cut off improperly.

---

Luckily, the links to the badges still work correctly, and I was able to find out that the second badge was for [stackexchange.com](/questions/tagged/stackexchange.com) and the third was for [stackexchange-2.0](/questions/tagged/stackexchange-2.0).

Can the issues outlined in the list above be fixed? Seems like all the things that could have gone wrong here have gone wrong.

Comment: **+1** for "It's a Stack Exchange muffin!".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the ellipses, it's by design. Tag badges can have [really-really-really-extremely-long-names-that-will-not-fit-anywhere](/questions/tagged/really-really-really-extremely-long-names-that-will-not-fit-anywhere) and the options we had were:

- Truncate with ellipsis
- Scrollbar
- Clip on the right side
- Wrap

This is what we opted to use.

I am fixing the tooltip and the link.

---

This is now done and it will be out in the next deployment

Comment: So maybe show the full name in the tooltip, at least for those with too  long name to fit?

Comment: But you can't even make the tag at the right actually go to the correct tag? There has to be *something* you can do to correctly identify the tag here.

Comment: Fixing. A few different issues were convoluted in one bug report.